# add Searchbox to polygon drawing google map

Tags: api, google-maps, search

I am using this below script to draw polygon to google map, which is working ok. I want to add searchbox to map. I tried a lot, But cannot embed searchbox.

http://bl.ocks.org/knownasilya/89a32e572989f0aff1f8

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Drawing Tools</title>
        <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=drawing"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            #map, html, body {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                width: 960px;
                height: 700px;
            }

            #panel {
                width: 200px;
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 13px;
                float: right;
                margin: 10px;
            }

            #color-palette {
                clear: both;
            }

            .color-button {
                width: 14px;
                height: 14px;
                font-size: 0;
                margin: 2px;
                float: left;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            #delete-button {
                margin-top: 5px;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var drawingManager;
            var selectedShape;
            var colors = ['#1E90FF', '#FF1493', '#32CD32', '#FF8C00', '#4B0082'];
            var selectedColor;
            var colorButtons = {};

            function clearSelection () {
                if (selectedShape) {
                    if (selectedShape.type !== 'marker') {
                        selectedShape.setEditable(false);
                    }

                    selectedShape = null;
                }
            }

            function setSelection (shape) {
                if (shape.type !== 'marker') {
                    clearSelection();
                    shape.setEditable(true);
                    selectColor(shape.get('fillColor') || shape.get('strokeColor'));
                }

                selectedShape = shape;
            }

            function deleteSelectedShape () {
                if (selectedShape) {
                    selectedShape.setMap(null);
                }
            }

            function selectColor (color) {
                selectedColor = color;
                for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; ++i) {
                    var currColor = colors[i];
                    colorButtons[currColor].style.border = currColor == color ? '2px solid #789' : '2px solid #fff';
                }

                // Retrieves the current options from the drawing manager and replaces the
                // stroke or fill color as appropriate.
                var polylineOptions = drawingManager.get('polylineOptions');
                polylineOptions.strokeColor = color;
                drawingManager.set('polylineOptions', polylineOptions);

                var rectangleOptions = drawingManager.get('rectangleOptions');
                rectangleOptions.fillColor = color;
                drawingManager.set('rectangleOptions', rectangleOptions);

                var circleOptions = drawingManager.get('circleOptions');
                circleOptions.fillColor = color;
                drawingManager.set('circleOptions', circleOptions);

                var polygonOptions = drawingManager.get('polygonOptions');
                polygonOptions.fillColor = color;
                drawingManager.set('polygonOptions', polygonOptions);
            }

            function setSelectedShapeColor (color) {
                if (selectedShape) {
                    if (selectedShape.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE) {
                        selectedShape.set('strokeColor', color);
                    } else {
                        selectedShape.set('fillColor', color);
                    }
                }
            }

            function makeColorButton (color) {
                var button = document.createElement('span');
                button.className = 'color-button';
                button.style.backgroundColor = color;
                google.maps.event.addDomListener(button, 'click', function () {
                    selectColor(color);
                    setSelectedShapeColor(color);
                });

                return button;
            }

            function buildColorPalette () {
                var colorPalette = document.getElementById('color-palette');
                for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; ++i) {
                    var currColor = colors[i];
                    var colorButton = makeColorButton(currColor);
                    colorPalette.appendChild(colorButton);
                    colorButtons[currColor] = colorButton;
                }
                selectColor(colors[0]);
            }

            function initialize () {
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    zoom: 16,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.25097, 20.97114),
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
                    disableDefaultUI: true,
                    zoomControl: true
                });

                var polyOptions = {
                    strokeWeight: 0,
                    fillOpacity: 0.45,
                    editable: true,
                    draggable: true
                };
                // Creates a drawing manager attached to the map that allows the user to draw
                // markers, lines, and shapes.
                drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
                    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
                    markerOptions: {
                        draggable: true
                    },
                    polylineOptions: {
                        editable: true,
                        draggable: true
                    },
                    rectangleOptions: polyOptions,
                    circleOptions: polyOptions,
                    polygonOptions: polyOptions,
                    map: map
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function (e) {
                    var newShape = e.overlay;

                    newShape.type = e.type;

                    if (e.type !== google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
                        // Switch back to non-drawing mode after drawing a shape.
                        drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);

                        // Add an event listener that selects the newly-drawn shape when the user
                        // mouses down on it.
                        google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', function (e) {
                            if (e.vertex !== undefined) {
                                if (newShape.type === google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON) {
                                    var path = newShape.getPaths().getAt(e.path);
                                    path.removeAt(e.vertex);
                                    if (path.length < 3) {
                                        newShape.setMap(null);
                                    }
                                }
                                if (newShape.type === google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE) {
                                    var path = newShape.getPath();
                                    path.removeAt(e.vertex);
                                    if (path.length < 2) {
                                        newShape.setMap(null);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            setSelection(newShape);
                        });
                        setSelection(newShape);
                    }
                    else {
                        google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', function (e) {
                            setSelection(newShape);
                        });
                        setSelection(newShape);
                    }
                });

                // Clear the current selection when the drawing mode is changed, or when the
                // map is clicked.
                google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'drawingmode_changed', clearSelection);
                google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', clearSelection);
                google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('delete-button'), 'click', deleteSelectedShape);

                buildColorPalette();
            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="panel">
            <div id="color-palette"></div>
            <div>
                <button id="delete-button">Delete Selected Shape</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="map"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to add searchbox with this script, After trying a lot I posted it. thank you for your precious time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [SearchBox example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox)

add the following code to your initialize function (be sure to include the places library in the API include):

```
// Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

// Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
  searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
});

var markers = [];
// Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
// more details for that place.
searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
  var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

  if (places.length == 0) {
    return;
  }

  // Clear out the old markers.
  markers.forEach(function(marker) {
    marker.setMap(null);
  });
  markers = [];

  // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  places.forEach(function(place) {
    if (!place.geometry) {
      console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
      return;
    }
    var icon = {
      url: place.icon,
      size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
    };

    // Create a marker for each place.
    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      icon: icon,
      title: place.name,
      position: place.geometry.location
    }));

    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      // Only geocodes have viewport.
      bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
    }
  });
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/c35b6mku/2/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var drawingManager;
var selectedShape;
var colors = ['#1E90FF', '#FF1493', '#32CD32', '#FF8C00', '#4B0082'];
var selectedColor;
var colorButtons = {};

function clearSelection() {
  if (selectedShape) {
    if (selectedShape.type !== 'marker') {
      selectedShape.setEditable(false);
    }

    selectedShape = null;
  }
}

function setSelection(shape) {
  if (shape.type !== 'marker') {
    clearSelection();
    shape.setEditable(true);
    selectColor(shape.get('fillColor') || shape.get('strokeColor'));
  }

  selectedShape = shape;
}

function deleteSelectedShape() {
  if (selectedShape) {
    selectedShape.setMap(null);
  }
}

function selectColor(color) {
  selectedColor = color;
  for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; ++i) {
    var currColor = colors[i];
    colorButtons[currColor].style.border = currColor == color ? '2px solid #789' : '2px solid #fff';
  }

  // Retrieves the current options from the drawing manager and replaces the
  // stroke or fill color as appropriate.
  var polylineOptions = drawingManager.get('polylineOptions');
  polylineOptions.strokeColor = color;
  drawingManager.set('polylineOptions', polylineOptions);

  var rectangleOptions = drawingManager.get('rectangleOptions');
  rectangleOptions.fillColor = color;
  drawingManager.set('rectangleOptions', rectangleOptions);

  var circleOptions = drawingManager.get('circleOptions');
  circleOptions.fillColor = color;
  drawingManager.set('circleOptions', circleOptions);

  var polygonOptions = drawingManager.get('polygonOptions');
  polygonOptions.fillColor = color;
  drawingManager.set('polygonOptions', polygonOptions);
}

function setSelectedShapeColor(color) {
  if (selectedShape) {
    if (selectedShape.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE) {
      selectedShape.set('strokeColor', color);
    } else {
      selectedShape.set('fillColor', color);
    }
  }
}

function makeColorButton(color) {
  var button = document.createElement('span');
  button.className = 'color-button';
  button.style.backgroundColor = color;
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(button, 'click', function() {
    selectColor(color);
    setSelectedShapeColor(color);
  });

  return button;
}

function buildColorPalette() {
  var colorPalette = document.getElementById('color-palette');
  for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; ++i) {
    var currColor = colors[i];
    var colorButton = makeColorButton(currColor);
    colorPalette.appendChild(colorButton);
    colorButtons[currColor] = colorButton;
  }
  selectColor(colors[0]);
}

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 16,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.25097, 20.97114),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    zoomControl: true
  });

  var polyOptions = {
    strokeWeight: 0,
    fillOpacity: 0.45,
    editable: true,
    draggable: true
  };
  // Creates a drawing manager attached to the map that allows the user to draw
  // markers, lines, and shapes.
  drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
    markerOptions: {
      draggable: true
    },
    polylineOptions: {
      editable: true,
      draggable: true
    },
    rectangleOptions: polyOptions,
    circleOptions: polyOptions,
    polygonOptions: polyOptions,
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
    var newShape = e.overlay;

    newShape.type = e.type;

    if (e.type !== google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
      // Switch back to non-drawing mode after drawing a shape.
      drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);

      // Add an event listener that selects the newly-drawn shape when the user
      // mouses down on it.
      google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', function(e) {
        if (e.vertex !== undefined) {
          if (newShape.type === google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON) {
            var path = newShape.getPaths().getAt(e.path);
            path.removeAt(e.vertex);
            if (path.length < 3) {
              newShape.setMap(null);
            }
          }
          if (newShape.type === google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE) {
            var path = newShape.getPath();
            path.removeAt(e.vertex);
            if (path.length < 2) {
              newShape.setMap(null);
            }
          }
        }
        setSelection(newShape);
      });
      setSelection(newShape);
    } else {
      google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', function(e) {
        setSelection(newShape);
      });
      setSelection(newShape);
    }
  });

  // Clear the current selection when the drawing mode is changed, or when the
  // map is clicked.
  google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'drawingmode_changed', clearSelection);
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', clearSelection);
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('delete-button'), 'click', deleteSelectedShape);

  buildColorPalette();

  // SearchBox code
  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });

  var markers = [];
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
  // more details for that place.
  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    // Clear out the old markers.
    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers = [];

    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place) {
      if (!place.geometry) {
        console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
        return;
      }
      var icon = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      // Create a marker for each place.
      markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      }));

      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });


}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
#map,
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 960px;
  height: 700px;
}

#panel {
  width: 200px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  float: right;
  margin: 10px;
}

#color-palette {
  clear: both;
}

.color-button {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 2px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#delete-button {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places,drawing&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
<div id="panel">
  <div id="color-palette"></div>
  <div>
    <button id="delete-button">Delete Selected Shape</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
```